# To break a message in two or more lines in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, newline, joptionpane

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+hostName.getText()+";" +
        "databaseName="+dbName.getText()+";user="+userName.getText()+";password="+password.getText()+";";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        if(con!=null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Connection Established");}
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
            //System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            //System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, cE.toString());
        }
```

When there is an error it shows a long JOptionPane message box that is longer than the width of the computer screen. How can I break e.toString() into two or more parts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;

class FixedWidthLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            String html = "<html><body width='%1s'><h1>Label Width</h1>"
                + "<p>Many Swing components support HTML 3.2 &amp; "
                + "(simple) CSS.  By setting a body width we can cause "
                + "the component to find the natural height needed to "
                + "display the component.<br><br>"
                + "<p>The body width in this text is set to %1s pixels.";
            // change to alter the width 
            int w = 175;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format(html, w, w));
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer saved me some headaches. Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `\n` to break the string in different lines. Or you can:

> Another way to accomplish this task is to subclass the JOptionPane
>   class and override the getMaxCharactersPerLineCount so that it returns
>   the number of characters that you want to represent as the maximum for
>   one line of text.

→ http://ninopriore.com/2009/07/12/the-java-joptionpane-class/ (dead link, see [archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20111219031912/http://ninopriore.com/2009/07/12/the-java-joptionpane-class/)).

Comment: The `line.separator` (which might not be `\n` BTW), will only work if the text is put into a multi-line component such as a `JTextArea`.  The component used to display a `String` in an option pane is a `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Andrew Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707397/3764804)'s answer, the following code let's you load an `HTML` file from the project root directory and display it in a `JOptionPane`. Note that you need to add a [Maven dependency for Apache Commons IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4). Also the use of [`HTMLCompressor`](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) is a good idea if you want to read formatted HTML code from a file without breaking the rendering.

```
import com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.HtmlCompressor;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HTMLRenderingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException
    {
        String html = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("document.html"));
        HtmlCompressor compressor = new HtmlCompressor();
        html = compressor.compress(html);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, html);
    }
}
```

This let's you manage the `HTML` code better than in Java Strings.

Don't forget to create a file named `document.html` with the following content:

```
<html>
<body width='175'><h1>Label Width</h1>

<p>Many Swing components support HTML 3.2 &amp; (simple) CSS. By setting a body width we can cause the component to find
    the natural height needed to display the component.<br><br>

<p>The body width in this text is set to 175 pixels.
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting a character limit, then search for the last space character in that environment and write an "\n" there. (Or I force the "\n" if there is no space character). Like this:

```
/** Force-inserts line breaks into an otherwise human-unfriendly long string.
 * */
private String breakLongString( String input, int charLimit )
{
    String output = "", rest = input;
    int i = 0;

     // validate.
    if ( rest.length() < charLimit ) {
        output = rest;
    }
    else if (  !rest.equals("")  &&  (rest != null)  )  // safety precaution
    {
        do
        {    // search the next index of interest.
            i = rest.lastIndexOf(" ", charLimit) +1;
            if ( i == -1 )
                i = charLimit;
            if ( i > rest.length() )
                i = rest.length();

             // break!
            output += rest.substring(0,i) +"\n";
            rest = rest.substring(i);
        }
        while (  (rest.length() > charLimit)  );
        output += rest;
    }

    return output;
}
```

And I call it like this in the (try)-catch bracket:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null, 
    "Could not create table 't_rennwagen'.\n\n"
    + breakLongString( stmt.getWarnings().toString(), 100 ), 
    "SQL Error", 
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
);
```